# Disable caching in WordPress Feeds generation

Tags: wordpress

i'm working on a plugin that adds another parameter to feeds, i want to add a numberOfItems on the url and the feed returns that number of articles. I dont want to use the builtin option from WP Admin because the feed will be added on other websites with different number of items, it's a little bit complicated, the point is i need this implementation. i've added something like

```
function _my_custom_option( $option )
{
global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;;
remove_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', '_my_custom_option' );
//$number = get_query_var('number');
$number = $wp_query->query_vars['numberOfItems'];

if(isset($number))
    $option = $number;
else
        $option = 10;
//$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', '_my_custom_option' );
return $option;
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_posts_per_rss', '_my_custom_option' );
```

It seems that the feed is cached somehow and doesnt generate with the number of items, because when i add paged=2, it works. But if i change on page=2 numberOfItems with another number, it doesnt change. Plus, i added some junk text in wp-includes >feed-rss2.php just to verify if it cached or not. And it doesnt show after the first 2-3 page refreshes.

To be honest, i'm stuck, i don't know how to approach this, i've looked on the wordpress code and i dont see where the caching is done.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
 function do_not_cache_feeds(&$feed) {
     $feed->enable_cache(false);
 }

 add_action( 'wp_feed_options', 'do_not_cache_feeds' );
```

Comment: It isnt about SimplePie and caching when parsing from another website. I'm trying to add a parameter to my feed url to show X articles instead of 10. Something like domain.com/feed?numberOfItems=3. The problem is the feed is somehow cached. When i try to view with a browser, it doesnt change the number of items i want, is cached.